# Convert a struct interface to an identical struct

Tags: go

Let's say I have two structs:

```
type Pet {
  Name string
}

type PetTwo {
  Name string
}
```

Now let's say that I convert Pet to an interface. How can I Type Assert PetTwo from the interface assuming that the package with which I am doing this from has no knowledge of the Pet type?

```
var ctx context.Context
pet := Pet{ Name : "Foo" }
ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "pet", pet)
petTwo := ctx.Value("pet").(PetTwo) // panics
fmt.Println(petTwo.Name) // prints "Foo"
```

Is there a way I can access the contents of pet without a type assertion?

I've tried to embed the structs in each other, type assertions, type assertions to unnamed types and more.

The main goal is to be able to access the contents of `Pet` from a package with no knowledge of the `Pet` type.

An ugly hack that achieves the goal is to marshal and unmarshal from json:

```
    jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(ctx.Value("pet"))
    var petTwo PetTwo
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &petTwo)
    fmt.Println(petTwo.Name) // prints "Foo"
```

Comment: Yes, will use the value to access the fields of `Pet`, in this case, the Name field.

Comment: If you have an interface value whose dynamic type your package does not import you won't be able to type assert it, as you already know, so you'll have to use reflection to convert it to a type your package has access to (PetTwo) and then type assert it to that type.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/EKdiOkE2WOH - you should, of course, first check that A can be converted to B by using the `ConvertibleTo` method of the `reflect.Type` type, otherwise the code will panic if passed in the wrong type.

Comment: Huh? You are mixing behavior (which is defined by interfaces) and values here. It is pretty simple: define the access to certain values as behavior of the interface, and you can implicitly convert to pet: https://play.golang.org/p/NGvA02k2og-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to access the Name field of an unknown type:

```
ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), "pet", Pet{"Fido"})
v := reflect.ValueOf(ctx.Value("pet"))
name := v.FieldByName("Name").String()
fmt.Println(name) // prints Fido
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/w_UCavJfxAa).